# PXE Installation of XenServer 6.2

Tags: networking, xenserver, installation, pxe-boot, xen

I've added XenServer 6.2 to our PXE/TFTP server. Everything went fine, but I cannot install XenServer as is. We get the XCP version instead of XenServer 6.2. Is this supposed to be normal?

Here are my configuration files:

answerfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <installation>
    <primary-disk>sda</primary-disk>
    <keymap>us</keymap>
    <admin-interface name="eth0" proto="dhcp" />
    <source type="url">http://pxeserver.domain.com/repos/xenserver</source>
    <timezone>America/Sao_Paulo</timezone>
  </installation>
```

pxelinux.cfg/default:

```
label E
    kernel mboot.c32
    append xenserver/xen.gz watchdog com1=115200,8n1i console=com1,tty --- xenserver/vmlinuz root=/dev/ram0 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 ramdisk_size=32758 answerfile=http://pxelinux.domain.com/repos/xenserver/answerfile --- xenserver/install.img
```

Folder structure inside /srv/repos/xenserver:

```
    /srv/repos/xenserver# ls
    answerfile packages.main packages.transfer-vm packages.xenserver
```

The folder packages.xenserver appears to be ignored, since only the packages.main are installed. I've tried putting the following line in the answerfile, but it failed:

```
<source type="url">http://pxeserver.domain.com/repos/xenserver/packages.xenserver</source>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

On the official Citrix Documentation (http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/4.0.1/installation/apc.html) theres no mention about copying the XS-REPOSITORY-LIST to the path of local repository. In my case /srv/repos/xenserver.

With this file in the correct place, everything was installed correctly through the network.